# Verilog: error instantiating module

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to write re-usable modules and have run into a problem.  The code follows:

```
35  always @(BTN) begin  
36    case (BTN)  
37      4'b0001:  
38        begin  
39          digit1 <= digit1 + 1;  
40          sevensegcase digi1 (      // the module i'm trying to reuse  
41            .SEG_SEL_IN(n2B0[1:0],  // n2B0 is a defined constant  
42            .BIN_IN(digit1[3:0]),  
43            .DOT_IN(n1B1),          // another constant  
44            .SEG_SEL_OUT(AN[3:0]),  // Send digit selection to the anodes  
45            .HEX_OUT(A_TO_G[7:0])); // Select appropriate segments  
46         end  

......  
......  
......
```

When I save the module, it compiles with errors.
When I Synthesize the module I get:

```
ERROR:HDLCompliers:26 - "Seven_Seg.v" line 40 unexpected token 'sevensegcase'
```

If I place the instantiation outside the always block I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating a module inside an `always @` block. Instantiate it outside the `always @` block, give it input wires, and in you `always @` block assign those input wires to desired signals.

```
sevensegcase digi1 (
  .SEG_SEL_IN(n2B0[1:0], // n2B0 is a defined constant
  .BIN_IN(digit1[3:0]),
  .DOT_IN(n1B1), // another constant
  .SEG_SEL_OUT(AN[3:0]), // Send digit selection to the anodes
  .HEX_OUT(A_TO_G[7:0])); // Select appropriate segments
)

reg digit_reg[3:0];

always @(BTN) begin
  case (BTN)
    4'b0001:
    begin
      digit_reg <= digit_reg + 1;
    end

assign digit1 = digit_reg;
```

Side note: Don't forget your `default:` case!

Comment: I would also recommend using automatic sensitivity lists `always @*` instead of `always @(BTN)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you may be swapping your module name and instance name. When you instantiate a module in Verilog it needs to be in the format:

```
module_name instance_name (port_a, port_b, ...);
```

I'm guessing that digi1 may be your module name and sevensegcase is the instance name? If so, you've transposed the order, and if you fix this, it should compile. Also, make sure you compile your submodule before the top module.